# Read/write files to Android device's external storage from a Windows application without using ADB

Tags: android, windows, usb

I am currently working on a project which requires files inside Android's external storage to be visible in a windows application. This windows application should be able to read/write to Android external storage (similar to file manager). I can use ADB but that requires the device to be put into developer mode which would not be a proper solution for an end to end application.

**My research on the web:**

After going through the ADB source code I find that they are using WinUSB APIs internally. WinUSB is a generic API which is applicable for all the USB devices like USB mouse, Ardunio boards etc. So I find it difficult to work with files (traversing/read/write) using WinUSB.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Your Windows aplication can use MTP to handle files on your Android device if connected with USB cable.

Comment: My target Windows OS is XP. Can you direct me to some links? I know that there is a Windows Portable Device API for MTP but that requires Windows7 at a minimum.

Comment: No i have no links. Not done that myself. Long live XP!

Answer (score 0):

We can use Windows Portable Devices API to read/write USB files. 
More Info: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389005(v=vs.85).aspx